# Motion detection system

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, arduino-uno

The code below works like this when there is something in front of the infrared sensor and the push button is press, the led light up keeps lighting up and the buzzer will keep buzzing, until press the button again to turn it off the led and the buzzer.

The few attempts I have tried are by putting if infrared_pin.read==0 before the state==1, but that code made it that I have to hold the push button and infrared sensor sense something to light up the led and the buzzer will buzz.I also try to make input_2=infrared_pin.read()==0 and to replace the infrared_pin_state==True,without infrared_pin_state=False in line 2 for code,the line 5 and 5,the if infrared_pin.read()==0  and infrared_pin_state=True.This also made it that I need to hold the button and infrared sensor need to sense something, for the led and buzzer to light up and buzz.

So I want the code below to work like I just press the button and when there is something infrared sensor, it will turn on the led and buzzer until I press the button again, it will turn off the buzzer and led. I thought that having the code to see if the push button is being pressed, then the infrared sensor something in front, will light up the led. Which part do I need to edit to make this possible? Please help me I am stuck at this for so long and not make any progress.

```
state=0
infrared_pin_state=False

while True:
  input=push_button.read()==1
  if infrared_pin.read()==0:
    infrared_pin_state=True
  if input == False:#have to press button to work
    if state ==1 and infrared_pin_state== True:# this is so the led will start in off
      led_pin.write(1)
      buzz_pin.write(1)
      print("Button pressed")
      state=0
      infrared_pin_state=False
  elif state ==0:
      led_pin.write(0)
      buzz_pin.write(0)
      print("Button depressed")
      state=1
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Try flowcharting out what you have and what you want, look at the differences.  This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: I edited it and I have try on my own, but I still cannot figure out, anyone can help me, I need it urgently.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the hardware you are using for this application, I can't give you exact code that has been thoroughly tested, so I am going to define a solution in general terms and provide a basic coding framework you shouldn be able to follow:

Problem Statement Upon pressing the Button the LED flashes and the Buzzer sounds whenever the Infrared detects an obstruction. The Buzzer continues to sound and the LED continues to flash until the Button & is pressed a second time. This can be mapped to a logic table as follows:
Let:
L = LED & L = 1 indicate Flashing
Z = Buzzer & Z = 1 indicate Sounding
I = Infrared & I = 1 indicate Obstruction
B = Button & B = 1 indicate Button State is pressed

Then:

```
B| I| | L| Z|
0| 0| | 0| 0|
0| 1| | 0| 0|
1| 1| | 1| 1|
0| 1| | 0| 0|
```

The above logic table shows a few issues with the problem description to include:

- What happens to the Led and the Buzzer if the obstruction goes away but the button has not been pressed a second time?
- What happens if the Button is pressed before the obstruction is detected?

For purposes of this design, the following assumptions are being made:

- In the event the obstruction goes away, the Led and Buzzer will stop.
- In the event the button is pressed before the obstruction is detected, the Buzzer and Led will sound.

Here is the code that I would recommend:

```
button_state = False  #Assumes Button starts unpressed
obstruction_state = False  #Assumes no Obstruction detected
while True:
    if push_button.read()==1:  #Pressed Button = 1
        button_state = !button_state  # flip the condition of button_state
        print('Button Pressed')
    if infrared_pin.read()==0:  #Obstruction Detected:
        obstruction_state = True
    else:
        obstruction_state = False
    if button_state and obstruction_state:
        led_pin.write(1)
        buzz_pin.write(1)
    else:
        led_pin.write(0)
        buzz_pin.write(0)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Since, I have no way to test with your hardware, you may need to make some adjustments.  Hopefully my comments will allow you to adjust as needed.